# Why does blazor navigateto execute @if logic in markup section of current page before navigating to destination page?

Tags: blazor-server-side

In server blazor's index.razor I have @if block in the markup. The logic in @code section of index.razor will use NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/somepage").  Here is my problem.  The NavigateTo works great but it executes the code in the @if block of index.razor before it eventually ends up on the destination page (somepage). I think you can see the potential problem.  To get around it I have hacked my code by keeping a session variable named IsNavigationInProgress which I set to true when using NavigateTo and placing this code in my index.razor:

```
<!-- 11/2/2023 Ken suspect bug in NavigateTo; it calls if logic in this page before navigating! -->
@if (KenSessionSvc.IsNavigationInProgress)
{
    KenSessionSvc.IsNavigationInProgress = false;
}
else if
{
    a bunch of code that should run for index.razor but causes harm when it gets executed when NavigateTo("/somepage") gets called. 
}
```

Update: Here is entire code in index.razor.  Breakpoint at line MyTest=... will show that the @if block is executed when the button is clicked to navigate to /counter.  The navigation works but the code in the @if block could set session variables that shouldn't be changing.

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<button type="button" @onclick=HandleGoTo>Go to counter</button>
@if (1==1)
{
    MyTest = "Some value that should not be changed when naviating to another page.";
    <div>
        Welcome to your new app.
    </div>
}

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<Counter IncrementBy=5></Counter>
@code {
    public string MyTest { get; set; }
    private void HandleGoTo()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what is triggering the navigation - if it is a UI event that could be the reason - can you share the code that triggers the navigation?